# Arithmetic sequence $\log(2),\log(2^x-1),\log(2^x+3),\ldots$

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

For which $x$ is

$$\log(2),\log(2^x-1),\log(2^x+3),\ldots$$

an arithmetic sequence?

**Solved:** For $d=\log(2)$, one gets the airthmetic sequence $$n\log(2)$$

Then you have to solve $$4=2^x-1$$

This means $2^x=5$, from which one attains $$8=2^x+3$$

From $2^x=5$ and $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$, deduce that

$$x=\frac{\log(5)}{\log(2)}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please don't just post a question without describing your attempt.

Comment: I tried to solve $\log(2^x-1)+d=\log(2^x+3)$ and $\log(2)+d=\log(2^x-1)$ separately, but I did not succeed.

Comment: I tried $$\log(4)=\log(2)+\log(2)=\log(2^x-1)$$ Having $2^x=5$. After that I get $$\log(2^x+3)=\log(8)=\log(4\cdot 2)=\log(2^x-1)+\log(2)$$ Using $\log(2^x)=x\log(2)$, gives $$x=\frac{\log(5)}{\log(2)}$$

Comment: It would help if you deleted your last note in favor of editing your query to include your work.

Comment: Hints: (1) A, B, C are in arithmetic progression means that (B-A) = (C-B). (2) $\log r - \log s = \log\left(\frac{r}{s}\right).$ (3) In working a problem that involves for example $a^x$, your life becomes easier if you let $u = a^x.$

Answer (score 1):

$\log(2)+\log(2^x+3)=2\log(2^x-1)=\log(2^x-1)^2.$

$2(2^x+3)=(2^x-1)^2= 2^{2x}-2\times2^x+1.$

$2^{2x}-4\times2^x-5=0.$

$(2^{x}-5)\times(2^x+1)=0.$

$2^{x}=5.$

$2^x=-1.$

Comment: No one said $x$ has to be real. $2^x=-1$ means $x=\frac{\pi i}{\ln 2}$